# How to show text randomly chosen from list when button is pressed?

Tags: java, arrays, string, button

I am trying to develop an app in eclipse that when the button is clicked randomly displays text from a string.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Your title and the body of your question don't match. Do you want to show text randomly chosen from a list or from a string?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for it. You make use of the Random() class or you use Math.random() to iterate through your string as an array of characters. Then you just choose random bits of it, until it's gone.

All you have to make sure of though, is that the arrays size is always checked so that you don't hit an OutOfBoundsException

Comment: you can asure to get a random element using something like `int random = (int)(Math.random() * theList.size());`, it will return a random value in [0, theList.size() - 1].